# SQL Server Backup does not run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-agent

After changing the `sa` password of SQL server 2012, the automatic backup doesn't run any more.

Please see the log history:

> [image: Log history]

The backup was not implemented by me.

> Login failed for user 'sa'.
>   Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.
>   [CLIENT: <local machine>]
>   09/18/2018 09:29:55,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 8.

Answer (score 2):

Seems lite this is a Maintenance Plan. find the plan in SSMS, modify it, and change the connection attribute for this so you use the correct password or perhaps even use windows authentication instead of hard-wiring a password in the maint plan.